# not able to deploy war file in tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ant

I am using spring, java 1.5 and tomcat 5.5.
Trying to deploy  war in tomcat, but when I am trying, it is giving only

```html
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

after that for printing full tomcat log trace, I have added following log4j.properties file under the WEB-INF/classes folder

```html
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender1,Appender2
log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=applog.txt
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

But after creating war file with ANT, log4j.properties automatically deleting

so please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Look into catalina.out file and you sould see what is Happening. BTW. Use a newer Version of Java. 1.5 is outdated for a Long time

Comment: WEB-INF/classes is created at compile time, so when you do the build log4j.properties will be deleted.
Usually, this is in resources folder, but if you really need it there, there you will need to adjust your build to copy it.

Comment: @Jens  there is no exception trace in catalina.out using this java version is my requirement :)